# Windows 8 Touch Events Global Hook in C#, Stylus Pressure and Angle

Tags: c#, windows-8, touch, hook, touch-event

There are some C# libraries that allow to capture mouse and keyboard events by listening to low level Windows calls by installing global hooks, but none of them allows capturing Windows 8 Stylus pressure. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what the Touch event ID is and an application that allows to listen all low level window events by ID , for example WM_KEYUP, specially those related to Touch events.

I was able to detect the stylus coordinates by listening to mouse and button events, but unable to get information about pressure. Any ideas?

In summary:
- Is there a C# library that allows the interception of Touch related events, specially the stylus, in a global way (not depending of a single application)?
- If not, does someone know the Hardware ID and Event IDs of Touch related events and how to decode their data? (I am looking for the pressure)
- Could someone recommend me an application to listen to and filter low level windows events by HID and Event name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any touch or stylus devices to test, but I guess you may use these win32 methods via pinvoke:

1. Hook low level mouse event using `SetWindowsHookEx` and id `WH_MOUSE_LL`.
2. In your `LowLevelMouseProc` callback, get your lParam which is a `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT` structure.
3. Check the `dwExtraInfo`, and see if there is any relationship with [system gestures.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tablet/system-events-and-mouse-messages)